# mongodb aggregate to filter relation in the field of the aggregate

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I have a `Transaction` collection like this :

```
{
  _id: ObjectId("5f1284078a7dd8a6b9140c97")
  company: ObjectId("5f127ce1e354f37df698f55e")
  person: ObjectId("5f1284078a7dd8a6b9140c95")
  actionTransaction: "Purchase"
}
```

`Companies` collection example:

```
{
  _id: ObjectId("5f127ce1e354f37df698f55e")
  name:  "MongoDB Inc"
  phoneNumber: "+1111111111"
  members: [
              {
                  _id: ObjectId("5f1284078a7dd8a6b9140c95")
                  title: "CEO"
                  role: "ADMIN"
              },
              {
                  _id: ObjectId("5f1284078a7ff8a6b9300d93")
                  title: "CHAIRMAN"
                  role: "Others"
              }
          ]
}
```

`People` collection example:

```
{
   _id: ObjectId("5f1284078a7dd8a6b9140c95")
   name: "Foo Bar"
   gender: "Male"
}
```

then I want to set a newfield on the aggregate , the new field called `personData` which filter the `company.members._id` equal with `person` in "Transaction" collection , and I always get null for this case when I query like this

```
db.transaction.aggregate(
 [

   { 
     $lookup: 
        {
            from: "companies",
            localField: "company",
            foreignField: "_id",
            as, "company"
        }
   },
   { $unwind: "$company" },
   {
     $set: {
        "personData": {
           $filter: {
              input: "$company.members"
              as: "theMembers"
              cond: {
                   { $eq : ["$$theMembers._id", "$person"]}
              }
           }
        }
      }
   }
 ]
)
```

personData always return  empty array here for me , is that idea for query this ?? I have look for all days but can't found any that work, and tried above , hope this make sense

thank you

Comment: Can you try to add `{ $unwind: "$company" }` after `$lookup` ?

Comment: I have tried it before, but doesn't work @mickl

Comment: Can you show the output of `$lookup` then?

Comment: `{ _id: ObjectId('5f127ce1e354f37df698f55e '), name: 'StackoverFlow Inc', members: [ {
                  _id: ObjectId("5f1284078a7dd8a6b9140c95")
                  title: "CEO"
                  role: "ADMIN"
              }, ] }`

Comment: the lookup company is like above question I mention for the members `company.members` and the rest only info of name company and things

Comment: Do you want something like this? [MongoPlayground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/I1AtYCuJ_Ap)

Comment: yes man, why my query above not work and it same like your query as well , do u know why ? @Valijon

Comment: You need to share sample data for both collections, so we can get out of the doubt

Comment: @Valijon just updated above, I added sample data for collections: `People`, `Transaction`, `Companies`, , I also ask those question on mongoDB developer , take a look this also https://developer.mongodb.com/community/forums/t/how-to-query-aggregate-to-get-result-only-object-instead-array/6828

Comment: I'm confused. Your SO aggregation is different from MongoDB forum. Post correct aggregation and expected output without cutting the information like this `{ COMPANY_DATA }`

Comment: yes It is different because I think the question on SO might make easier than on forum, it means { COMPANY_DATA } is the data company collection, because I dont want to write much code on question, it gonna not make questions not acceptable, so I short it like that :D @Valijon